# XQuery - determine whether a given UTC time falls in daylight saving time in a given timezone

Tags: timezone, xquery, dst

In XQuery, how can I determine whether a UTC time falls within daylight saving time in a region?

Something like:

```
declare function local:IsDaylightSavingTime($utcDateTime as xs:utcDateTime, timeZone xs:dayTimeDuration) as xs:boolean {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

How would you expect a time zone to be represented by an `xs:dayTimeDuration`? That would assume a time zone is the same thing as a time zone offset, which it is not.  Please read the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Besides, any program that is capable of performing this function needs some type of time zone database.  While it is conceivable that a particular XQuery *implementation* decided to incorporate a time zone database, that certainly wouldn't be in the XQuery language itself.